# Comparison of two normal distribution

Tags: comparison, gaussian, similarity, normal-distribution

I have two normally distributed samples. I want to know how close or similar it is. I tried few methods to find the similarity, like z-score and [bhattacharyya distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance).

Bhattacharyya distance didn't work for me. It gives the same distance if the standard deviation of two samples is same. It doesn't change with change in mean.

I want to know whether any method is available that take the samples or its mean and standard deviation to find the similarity or similarity rank something like this.

I am not from mathematics background, so please ignore the terminology mistakes and let me know if any clarification is required.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're not looking for a relationship between the two samples, where a correlation coefficient would be appropriate?
I've been investigating a similar question for my current data and am looking at the [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) and the [Earthmovers distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance).
I found [this post from a different forum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13504/testing-closeness-of-data/13691) which gave me a few ideas